# Report type permission for certain user

Tags: rest-api

I have some reports i want to give permission of report type for certain user.How i can give in salesforce.I want to give edit permission for some user.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Manage Custom Report Types documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=reports_manage_report_type.htm&siteLang=ja_3&type=0&language=en_US), in order to edit a custom report type, a user must have the **Manage Custom Report Types** profile permission.

You can grant this permission to a specific user by using a [permission set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_create.htm&language=en&type=0).

Comment: I have a profile Admin Profile - Force.com which is assigned to 4 users.But when i  m checking in my profile Manage Custom Report Types option is not showing.But in Sysytem admin profile the option is showing.Plz tell me if the option is not showing how can i assign edit report type permission to 4 users..

Answer (score 1):

A report type defines the set of records and fields available to a report based on the relationships between a primary object and its related objects.

A report type with deployed status is available for use in the report wizard. While in development, report types are visible only to authorized administrators and their delegates.

Now if you want to give access to some users that they can go and make changes in report type then you have to give "Manage Custom Report Type" permission like Jason Walke has said in his answer.

Then if you want to restrict access to the reports which are created by using that report type put those reports into a folder and assign permissions on that folder.